# Linux Skype: how to show contacts who are offline?

Tags: linux, skype

I've done something stupid to my Linux Skype configuration.  Only my online contacts are shown—it's as if my offline contacts don't exist.  This is a problem when I'm trying to figure out if someone is a contact already or not.
The screen shot below shows the story.  **How can I make my *offline* contacts appear on this screen?**

[image]

N.B. Answers for the Windows interface are *not* helpful—the Linux interface is completely different.

P.S. Search has been unhelpful, as the results are swamped by questions about people who wish to appear offline when they're not.

Comment: #Norman you didn't do anything stupid. Skype client for Linux is stupid. It should be an option somewhere for hiding/showing offline contacts. I would never solve it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pres <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to hide/unhide offline contacts.

It worked in Linux Skype 2.2.0.25

Reference:

> [Hide offline contacts in contact list window](https://jira.skype.com/browse/SCL-55)

I hope this helps !

Comment: Thx!! (Why tf is this not in one of the menus??)